# Can this Indian teenager resist 11kV electric shocks without dying?

Tags: biology, electromagnetism, india

Many online sources report on the Indian teenager Deepak Jangra ([Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2919960/I-m-human-lightbulb-16-year-old-electric-boy-India-withstand-shocking-11-000-volts-without-feeling-thing.html), [Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/meet-electric-boy-who-baffles-5029816)) who claims to be able to resist 11kV electric shocks.

They include images of him touching an exposed mains wire powering a lightbulb to his tongue, and also claimed that he touched the 11kV live wire powering the village without any negative effects.

> To find out, Deepak decided to test his limits by climbing an electric pole in a nearby field to touch the 11,000 voltage high-tension wire that powers his village.
>
> Soon, a crowd had gathered beneath him and started screaming in fear as they thought he was trying to commit suicide.
>
> Deepak said: ‘I was hanging from the pole touching the wires and I think people thought I was crazy.

Did Deepak Jangra actually form a ground circuit with the live wire of a 11kV supply and survive?

Comment: You've probably survived shocks of the same magnitude yourself with little more than a bit of discomfort.  Static discharges are very high voltage, but the current is negligible.  There could be some trickery involved that is dropping the current on those lines to very low levels so he can pull that stunt off

Comment: Touching high tension lines is not a great trick- birds do it all the time, and helicopters are used to service energized lines with hundreds of kV. If the kid was on a fairly dry wood or concrete pole the current might not be fatal. If he was on a grounded metal pole, and touched an actual power line that was 11kV wrt ground, he would definitely have died like [this](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xfyyii_man-electrocuted-on-the-train-india_news) warning-graphic.